# javascript hide show

Tags: javascript, php, hide, show

I'm trying to do a simple hide and show function in javascript (NOT Jquery please, I want to learn); and yes I'm still learning. What I'm trying to do is Facebook and other apps that when you hover on a news feed article, there's a small X that shows that serves as an option to delete that. I'm trying to do that on tables (table cell)

here's my header function:

```
function showHide(id) {
    if(document.getDocumentById(id).style.visibility == 'hidden')
        document.getDocumentById(id).style.visibility = 'visible';
    else
        document.getDocumentById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

and in the body (php):

```
echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="managealbum_delete" id="managealbum_delete'.$x.'">X</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $album->title . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $album->caption . '</td>';
        echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black;" onMouseOver="showHide('."'".'managealbum_delete'.$x."'".');" onMouseOut="showHide('."'".'managealbum_delete'.$x."'".');">' . $album->media . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: FYI I don't think you will be able to click the X as it is in a different cell than the mouse in/out event. Every time you leave the cell with the album->media output to click the X you will invoke the mouse out function. The event handlers should probably be defined for the tr...if a tr can handle that event.

Comment: oh yes, I moved it to a cell because I thought the code just doesn't work on <tr>'s . I moved it back to the tr

Answer (score 3):

The function is `getElementById`, not `getDocumentById`

```
function showHide(id) { 
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility == 'hidden')    
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    else 
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

Also, you can shorten it a bit, and check to make sure an element was found like this:

```
function showHide(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if( el && el.style.visibility == 'hidden')    
        el.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    else 
        el.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU omg. working late at night takes a toll... the minimalization of the code is good suggestion too. Makes me learn good practices

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to hide it and not just erase its content you should use:

```
document.getDocumentById(id).style.display = 'none';
```

And to show it (TDs), use:

```
document.getDocumentById(id).style.display = 'table-cell';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp